# Where do I go to find details of changes to IE between versions?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a website that works correctly on one machine, running IE 11.0.33.  The client is running IE 11.0.35, and is reporting an error I cannot reproduce.  Is there someplace I can go that outlines exactly what changed in the intervening versions (34 and 35) that can help me diagnose what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that the one browser is not running in IE8 mode or some other mode?

Comment: Using the F12 Developer tools, I confirmed that both instances are rendering the page in Edge mode, but one is acting different from the other.  I'd like to eliminate the version as a possible variable, and have asked the 11.0.33 be upgraded to 11.0.35, but if it then causes it to have the issue, I will be back at square one, wanting to know what the differences are.

Comment: see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/02/28/activex-filtering-for-consumers/ more than likely it is your test environment or your IE security zone settings that are the difference in rendering. Not the IE release or update version. Use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE security zone your test/production environments map to.

Comment: Set up IE to record blocked content and xss errors and warnings... Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"... If you are using a wordpress framework.... the IE ActiveX filtering is known block flash adds which fall back to <img> tags which are incorrectly sized... you can do nothing about it except add feature detection for ActiveX filtering see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/05/02/activex-filtering-for-developers/ ..... Include links to your website or a jsfiddle mashup with your questions (ALWAYS)